# Properly Handling Errors in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working with VBA for quite a while now, but I'm still not so sure about Error Handling.

A good article is the one of 
 [CPearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

However I'm still wondering if the way I used to do ErrorHandling was/is completely wrong:
**Block 1**

```
On Error Goto ErrCatcher
   If UBound(.sortedDates) > 0 Then

       // Code

   Else
ErrCatcher:
       // Code

   End If
```

The if clause, because if it is true, will be executed and if it fails the Goto will go into the Else-part, since the Ubound of an Array should never be zero or less, without an Error, this method worked quite well so far.

If I understood it right it should be like this:

**Block 2**

```
On Error Goto ErrCatcher
    If Ubound(.sortedDates) > 0 Then

       // Code
    End If

    Goto hereX

ErrCatcher:
       //Code
    Resume / Resume Next / Resume hereX

hereX:
```

Or even like this:
**Block 3**

```
On Error Goto ErrCatcher
    If Ubound(.sortedDates) > 0 Then

       // Code
    End If

ErrCatcher:
    If Err.Number <> 0 then
       //Code
    End If
```

The most common way I see is that one, that the Error "Catcher" is at the end of a sub and the Sub actually ends before with a "Exit Sub", but however isn't it a little confusing if the Sub is quite big if you jump vice versa to read through the code?

**Block 4**

> Source of the following Code: 
>    [CPearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

```
  On Error Goto ErrHandler:
   N = 1 / 0    ' cause an error
   '
   ' more code
   '
  Exit Sub

  ErrHandler:

   ' error handling code'

   Resume Next

End Sub
```

Should it be like in Block 3 ?

Comment: rather than risk throwing an error with `If Ubound(.sortedDates)>0` use [If IsArrayAllocated(.sortedDates) = TRUE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/isarrayallocated.aspx)

Comment: Wow! that was fast :-) - thank you, that makes the *On Error Goto* unnecessary here...

Comment: But if it wasn't an array check.. though I can't of any other case.. I think my question is answered like this - there's no way to vote up your comment is there?, because it's a really good one :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't use Block1. It doesn't seem right having the Error block in an IF statement unrelated to Errors.

Blocks 2,3 & 4 I guess are variations of a theme. I prefer the use of Blocks 3 & 4 over 2 only because of a dislike of the GOTO statement; I generally use the Block4 method. This is one example of code I use to check if the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library is added and if not add or use an earlier version if 2.8 is not available.

```
Option Explicit
Public booRefAdded As Boolean 'one time check for references

Public Sub Add_References()
Dim lngDLLmsadoFIND As Long

If Not booRefAdded Then
    lngDLLmsadoFIND = 28 ' load msado28.tlb, if cannot find step down versions until found

        On Error GoTo RefErr:
            'Add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8
            Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.references.AddFromFile _
            Environ("CommonProgramFiles") + "\System\ado\msado" & lngDLLmsadoFIND & ".tlb"

        On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub

RefErr:
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 0
                'no error
            Case 1004
                 'Enable Trust Centre Settings
                 MsgBox ("Certain VBA References are not available, to allow access follow these steps" & Chr(10) & _
                 "Goto Excel Options/Trust Centre/Trust Centre Security/Macro Settings" & Chr(10) & _
                 "1. Tick - 'Disable all macros with notification'" & Chr(10) & _
                 "2. Tick - 'Trust access to the VBA project objects model'")
                 End
            Case 32813
                 'Err.Number 32813 means reference already added
            Case 48
                 'Reference doesn't exist
                 If lngDLLmsadoFIND = 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Cannot Find Required Reference")
                    End
                Else
                    For lngDLLmsadoFIND = lngDLLmsadoFIND - 1 To 0 Step -1
                           Resume
                    Next lngDLLmsadoFIND
                End If

            Case Else
                 MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
                End
        End Select

        On Error GoTo 0
End If
booRefAdded = TRUE
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. And thanks for the example!
That's a good idea to check for the references.

I think I'll go for Block 3 or 4.

Actually if I'd use Block 3  can I continue with the normal Code without adding further statements of the Error Catching or should I write **On Error Goto 0** ?

Comment: Probably I should - since you used it as well

Comment: The last "On Error GoTo 0" gets ignored.  It has effect only if it's not handling an error at the time it's executed.

Answer (score 56):

You've got one truly marvelous answer from ray023, but your comment that it's probably overkill is apt. For a "lighter" version....

**Block 1** is, IMHO, bad practice. As already pointed out by osknows, mixing error-handling with normal-path code is Not Good. For one thing, if a *new* error is thrown while there's an Error condition in effect you will **not** get an opportunity to handle it (unless you're calling from a routine that also has an error handler, where the execution will "bubble up").

**Block 2** looks like an imitation of a Try/Catch block. It should be okay, but it's not The VBA Way. **Block 3** is a variation on Block 2.

**Block 4** is a bare-bones version of The VBA Way. I would *strongly* advise using it, or something like it, because it's what any other VBA programmer inherting the code will expect. Let me present a small expansion, though:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Dim as required

'functional code that might throw errors

ExitSub:
    'any always-execute (cleanup?) code goes here -- analagous to a Finally block.
    'don't forget to do this -- you don't want to fall into error handling when there's no error
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'can Select Case on Err.Number if there are any you want to handle specially

    'display to user
    MsgBox "Something's wrong: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description

    'or use a central DisplayErr routine, written Public in a Module
    DisplayErr Err.Number, Err.Description

    Resume ExitSub
    Resume
End Sub
```

Note that second `Resume`. This is a trick I learned recently: It will *never* execute in normal processing, since the `Resume <label>` statement will send the execution elsewhere. It can be a godsend for debugging, though. When you get an error notification, choose Debug (or press Ctl-Break, then choose Debug when you get the "Execution was interrupted" message). The next (highlighted) statement will be either the `MsgBox` or the following statement. Use "Set Next Statement" (Ctl-F9) to highlight the bare `Resume`, then press F8. This will show you *exactly* where the error was thrown.

As to your objection to this format "jumping around", A) it's what VBA programmers expect, as stated previously, & B) your routines *should* be short enough that it's not far to jump.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I still need to get used to the VBA-Error Handling... And thank you for the Resume  <Label> - Resume trick! 
Well my routines got more or less quite long, but I've splitted it in about 10 Modules and tried to decrease the sizes of the routines... surely it could have been done better, but I'm trying to improve it

Comment: All good answers here, but +1 for the including ExitSub: I've found that consistently exiting a sub has overall helped my error handling and coding. I always put all my cleanup code in that block. I usually put an 'On Error GoTo 0' as the first line in that code block as well, so that, theoretically, VBA won't throw an error in my cleanup code, which is usually what I want.

Comment: @Steve--Actually, what `On Error GoTo 0` does is turn off error *handling*, so that if an error is thrown you only get VB(A)'s default of a message box with error number & description and the options to End or Debug. When I'm doing something semi-risky (say, closing a DB connection that may or may not be open, where all I care about is that it's *not open* when I'm done), I put `On Error Resume Next` ahead of it. This makes VB(A) ignore the error.

Comment: @skofgar--I owe that trick to *Access 2007 Progammer's Reference* from Wrox. Almost worth the price of the book by itself.

Comment: the `On Error GoTo 0` was really useful to me, because I had the Problem that a `On Error Resume Next`-block not only ignored the Errors in the part i wanted it to, but also in the entire code following, which I wasn't aware of. But thanks to you all here at StackOverflow, I'll be able to write better code with better error handling :-)

Answer (score 25):

Two main purposes for error handling:

1. Trap errors you can
   predict but can't control the user
   from doing (e.g. saving a file to a
   thumb drive when the thumb drives
   has been removed)
2. For unexpected errors, present user with a form
   that informs them what the problem
   is.  That way, they can relay that
   message to you and you might be able
   to give them a work-around while you
   work on a fix.

So, how would you do this?

First of all, create an error form to display when an unexpected error occurs.

It could look something like this (FYI: Mine is called frmErrors):
[image: Company Error Form]

Notice the following labels:

- lblHeadline
- lblSource
- lblProblem
- lblResponse

Also, the standard command buttons:

- Ignore
- Retry
- Cancel

There's nothing spectacular in the code for this form:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
  Me.Tag = CMD_CANCEL
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdIgnore_Click()
  Me.Tag = CMD_IGNORE
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdRetry_Click()
  Me.Tag = CMD_RETRY
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Me.lblErrorTitle.Caption = "Custom Error Title Caption String"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  'Prevent user from closing with the Close box in the title bar.
    If CloseMode <> 1 Then
      cmdCancel_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, you want to know which button the user pressed when the form closes.

Next, create an Error Handler Module that will be used throughout your VBA app:

```
'****************************************************************
'    MODULE: ErrorHandler
'
'   PURPOSE: A VBA Error Handling routine to handle
'             any unexpected errors
'
'     Date:    Name:           Description:
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'03/22/2010    Ray      Initial Creation
'****************************************************************
Option Explicit

Global Const CMD_RETRY = 0
Global Const CMD_IGNORE = 1
Global Const CMD_CANCEL = 2
Global Const CMD_CONTINUE = 3

Type ErrorType
    iErrNum As Long
    sHeadline As String
    sProblemMsg As String
    sResponseMsg As String
    sErrorSource As String
    sErrorDescription As String
    iBtnCap(3) As Integer
    iBitmap As Integer
End Type

Global gEStruc As ErrorType
Sub EmptyErrStruc_S(utEStruc As ErrorType)
  Dim i As Integer
    
  utEStruc.iErrNum = 0
  utEStruc.sHeadline = ""
  utEStruc.sProblemMsg = ""
  utEStruc.sResponseMsg = ""
  utEStruc.sErrorSource = ""
  For i = 0 To 2
    utEStruc.iBtnCap(i) = -1
  Next
  utEStruc.iBitmap = 1

End Sub
Function FillErrorStruct_F(EStruc As ErrorType) As Boolean
  'Must save error text before starting new error handler
  'in case we need it later
  EStruc.sProblemMsg = Error(EStruc.iErrNum)
  On Error GoTo vbDefaultFill

  EStruc.sHeadline = "Error " & Format$(EStruc.iErrNum)
  EStruc.sProblemMsg = EStruc.sErrorDescription
  EStruc.sErrorSource = EStruc.sErrorSource
  EStruc.sResponseMsg = "Contact the Company and tell them you received Error # " & Str$(EStruc.iErrNum) & ". You should write down the program function you were using, the record you were working with, and what you were doing."
  
   Select Case EStruc.iErrNum
       'Case Error number here
       'not sure what numeric errors user will ecounter, but can be implemented here
       'e.g.
       'EStruc.sHeadline = "Error 3265"
       'EStruc.sResponseMsg = "Contact tech support. Tell them what you were doing in the program."

     Case Else
       
       EStruc.sHeadline = "Error " & Format$(EStruc.iErrNum) & ": " & EStruc.sErrorDescription
       EStruc.sProblemMsg = EStruc.sErrorDescription
      
   End Select
   
   GoTo FillStrucEnd
   
vbDefaultFill:

  'Error Not on file
  EStruc.sHeadline = "Error " & Format$(EStruc.iErrNum) & ": Contact Tech Support"
  EStruc.sResponseMsg = "Contact the Company and tell them you received Error # " & Str$(EStruc.iErrNum)
FillStrucEnd:

  Exit Function

End Function
Function iErrorHandler_F(utEStruc As ErrorType) As Integer
  Static sCaption(3) As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim iMCursor As Integer
  
  Beep

  'Setup static array
  If Len(sCaption(0)) < 1 Then
    sCaption(CMD_IGNORE) = "&Ignore"
    sCaption(CMD_RETRY) = "&Retry"
    sCaption(CMD_CANCEL) = "&Cancel"
    sCaption(CMD_CONTINUE) = "Continue"
  End If

  Load frmErrors
  
  'Did caller pass error info?  If not fill struc with the needed info
  If Len(utEStruc.sHeadline) < 1 Then
    i = FillErrorStruct_F(utEStruc)
  End If

  frmErrors!lblHeadline.Caption = utEStruc.sHeadline
  frmErrors!lblProblem.Caption = utEStruc.sProblemMsg
  frmErrors!lblSource.Caption = utEStruc.sErrorSource
  frmErrors!lblResponse.Caption = utEStruc.sResponseMsg
  
  frmErrors.Show
  iErrorHandler_F = frmErrors.Tag   ' Save user response
  Unload frmErrors                  ' Unload and release form

  EmptyErrStruc_S utEStruc          ' Release memory

End Function
```

You may have errors that will be custom only to your application.    This would typically be a short list of errors specifically only to your application.
If you don't already have a constants module, create one that will contain an ENUM of your custom errors.  (NOTE:  Office '97 does NOT support ENUMS.). The ENUM should look something like this:

```
Public Enum CustomErrorName
  MaskedFilterNotSupported
  InvalidMonthNumber
End Enum
```

Create a module that will throw your custom errors.

```
'********************************************************************************************************************************
'    MODULE: CustomErrorList
'
'   PURPOSE: For trapping custom errors applicable to this application
'
'INSTRUCTIONS:  To use this module to create your own custom error:
'               1.  Add the Name of the Error to the CustomErrorName Enum
'               2.  Add a Case Statement to the raiseCustomError Sub
'               3.  Call the raiseCustomError Sub in the routine you may see the custom error
'               4.  Make sure the routine you call the raiseCustomError has error handling in it
'
'
'     Date:    Name:           Description:
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'03/26/2010    Ray       Initial Creation
'********************************************************************************************************************************
Option Explicit
Const MICROSOFT_OFFSET = 512 'Microsoft reserves error values between vbObjectError and vbObjectError + 512
'************************************************************************************************
'  FUNCTION:  raiseCustomError
'
'   PURPOSE:  Raises a custom error based on the information passed
'
'PARAMETERS:  customError - An integer of type CustomErrorName Enum that defines the custom error
'             errorSource - The place the error came from
'
'   Returns:  The ASCII vaule that should be used for the Keypress
'
'     Date:    Name:           Description:
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'03/26/2010    Ray       Initial Creation
'************************************************************************************************
Public Sub raiseCustomError(customError As Integer, Optional errorSource As String = "")
  Dim errorLong As Long
  Dim errorDescription As String
  
  errorLong = vbObjectError + MICROSOFT_OFFSET + customError
  
  Select Case customError
  
    Case CustomErrorName.MaskedFilterNotSupported
      errorDescription = "The mask filter passed is not supported"
      
    Case CustomErrorName.InvalidMonthNumber
      errorDescription = "Invalid Month Number Passed"
      
    Case Else
      errorDescription = "The custom error raised is unknown."
      
  End Select
  
  Err.Raise errorLong, errorSource, errorDescription
  
End Sub
```

You are now well equipped to trap errors in your program.  You sub (or function), should look something like this:

```
Public Sub MySub(monthNumber as Integer)
  On Error GoTo eh  
  
  Dim sheetWorkSheet As Worksheet
  
  'Run Some code here
  
  '************************************************
  '*   OPTIONAL BLOCK 1:  Look for a specific error
  '************************************************
  'Temporarily Turn off Error Handling so that you can check for specific error
  On Error Resume Next
  'Do some code where you might expect an error.  Example below:
  Const ERR_SHEET_NOT_FOUND = 9 'This error number is actually subscript out of range, but for this example means the worksheet was not found
  
  Set sheetWorkSheet = Sheets("January")
  
  'Now see if the expected error exists
  
  If Err.Number = ERR_SHEET_NOT_FOUND Then
    MsgBox "Hey!  The January worksheet is missing.  You need to recreate it."
    Exit Sub
  ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Uh oh...there was an error we did not expect so just run basic error handling 
    GoTo eh
  End If
  
  'Finished with predictable errors, turn basic error handling back on:
  On Error GoTo eh
  
  '**********************************************************************************
  '*   End of OPTIONAL BLOCK 1
  '**********************************************************************************
  
  '**********************************************************************************
  '*   OPTIONAL BLOCK 2:  Raise (a.k.a. "Throw") a Custom Error if applicable
  '**********************************************************************************
  If not (monthNumber >=1 and monthnumber <=12) then
    raiseCustomError CustomErrorName.InvalidMonthNumber, "My Sub"
  end if
  '**********************************************************************************
  '*   End of OPTIONAL BLOCK 2
  '**********************************************************************************
  
  'Rest of code in your sub
  
  goto sub_exit

eh:
  gEStruc.iErrNum = Err.Number
  gEStruc.sErrorDescription = Err.Description
  gEStruc.sErrorSource = Err.Source
  m_rc = iErrorHandler_F(gEStruc)
  
  If m_rc = CMD_RETRY Then
    Resume
  End If

sub_exit:
  'Any final processing you want to do.
  'Be careful with what you put here because if it errors out, the error rolls up.  This can be difficult to debug; especially if calling routine has no error handling.
  
  Exit Sub 'I was told a long time ago (10+ years) that exit sub was better than end sub...I can't tell you why, so you may not want to put in this line of code.  It's habit I can't break :P
End Sub
```

A copy/paste of the code above may not work right out of the gate, but should definitely give you the gist.

Comment: thank you very much for this Error Handler :-) It looks quite good, however it is probably an Overkill for the tool I'm working on. But still.. maybe I'll implement it :-) BTW The logo is marvelous :D I'll keep you posted if I need one like this

Comment: The logo is gone :(

Answer (score 6):

I keep things simple:
At the module level I define two variables and set one to the name of the module itself.

```
    Private Const ThisModuleName            As String = "mod_Custom_Functions"
    Public sLocalErrorMsg                   As String
```

Within each Sub/Function of the module I define a local variable

```
    Dim ThisRoutineName                     As String
```

I set ThisRoutineName to the name of the sub or function

```
' Housekeeping
    On Error Goto ERR_RTN
    ThisRoutineName = "CopyWorksheet"
```

I then send all errors to an ERR_RTN: when they occur, but I first set the sLocalErrorMsg to define what the error actually is and provide some debugging info.

```
    If Len(Trim(FromWorksheetName)) < 1 Then
        sLocalErrorMsg = "Parameter 'FromWorksheetName' Is Missing."
        GoTo ERR_RTN
    End If
```

At the bottom of each sub/function, I direct the logic flow as follows

```
    '
    ' The "normal" logic goes here for what the routine does
    '
    GoTo EXIT_RTN

    ERR_RTN:

        On Error Resume Next

    ' Call error handler if we went this far.
        ErrorHandler ThisModuleName, ThisRoutineName, sLocalErrorMsg, Err.Description, Err.Number, False

    EXIT_RTN:

        On Error Resume Next
     '
     ' Some closing logic
     '
    End If
```

I then have a seperate module I put in all projects called "mod_Error_Handler".

```
    '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Subroutine Name:     ErrorHandler                                                     '
    '                                                                                       '
    ' Description:                                                                          '
    '   This module will handle the common error alerts.                                    '
    '                                                                                       '
    ' Inputs:                                                                               '
    '   ModuleName                String    'The name of the module error is in.            '
    '   RoutineName               String    'The name of the routine error in in.           '
    '   LocalErrorMsg             String    'A local message to assist with troubleshooting.'
    '   ERRDescription            String    'The Windows Error Description.                 '
    '   ERRCode                   Long      'The Windows Error Code.                        '
    '   Terminate                 Boolean   'End program if error encountered?              '
    '                                                                                       '
    ' Revision History:                                                                     '
    ' Date (YYYYMMDD) Author                Change                                          '
    ' =============== ===================== =============================================== '
    ' 20140529        XXXXX X. XXXXX        Original                                        '
    '                                                                                       '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '
    Public Sub ErrorHandler(ModuleName As String, RoutineName As String, LocalErrorMsg As String, ERRDescription As String, ERRCode As Long, Terminate As Boolean)
        Dim sBuildErrorMsg                 As String

    ' Build Error Message To Display
        sBuildErrorMsg = "Error Information:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        If Len(Trim(ModuleName)) < 1 Then
            ModuleName = "Unknown"
        End If

        If Len(Trim(RoutineName)) < 1 Then
           RoutineName = "Unknown"
        End If

        sBuildErrorMsg = sBuildErrorMsg & "Module Name:        " & ModuleName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        sBuildErrorMsg = sBuildErrorMsg & "Routine Name:       " & RoutineName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        If Len(Trim(LocalErrorMsg)) > 0 Then
            sBuildErrorMsg = sBuildErrorMsg & "Local Error Msg:    " & LocalErrorMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        End If

        If Len(Trim(ERRDescription)) > 0 Then
            sBuildErrorMsg = sBuildErrorMsg & "Program Error Msg:  " & ERRDescription & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            If IsNumeric(ERRCode) Then
                sBuildErrorMsg = sBuildErrorMsg & "Program Error Code: " & Trim(Str(ERRCode)) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If

        MsgBox sBuildErrorMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error Detected!"

        If Terminate Then
            End
        End If

    End Sub
```

The end result is a pop-up error message teling me in what module, what soubroutine, and what the error message specifically was.  In addition, it also will insert the Windows error message and code.

Answer (score 2):

Block 2 doesn't work because it doesn't reset the Error Handler potentially causing an endless loop. For Error Handling to work properly in VBA, you need a `Resume` statement to clear the Error Handler. The `Resume` also reactivates the previous Error Handler. Block 2 fails because a new error would go back to the previous Error Handler causing an infinite loop.

Block 3 fails because there is no `Resume` statement so any attempt at error handling after that will fail.

Every error handler must be ended by exiting the procedure or a `Resume` statement. Routing normal execution around an error handler is confusing. This is why error handlers are usually at the bottom.

But here is another way to handle an error in VBA. It handles the error inline like Try/Catch in VB.net There are a few pitfalls, but properly managed it works quite nicely.

```
Sub InLineErrorHandling()

    'code without error handling

BeginTry1:

    'activate inline error handler
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler1

        'code block that may result in an error
        Dim a As String: a = "Abc"
        Dim c As Integer: c = a 'type mismatch

ErrHandler1:

    'handle the error
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        'the error handler has deactivated the previous error handler

        MsgBox (Err.Description)

        'Resume (or exit procedure) is the only way to get out of an error handling block
        'otherwise the following On Error statements will have no effect
        'CAUTION: it also reactivates the previous error handler
        Resume EndTry1
    End If

EndTry1:
    'CAUTION: since the Resume statement reactivates the previous error handler
    'you must ALWAYS use an On Error GoTo statement here
    'because another error here would cause an endless loop
    'use On Error GoTo 0 or On Error GoTo <Label>
    On Error GoTo 0

    'more code with or without error handling

End Sub
```

Sources:

- http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258159.aspx

The key to making this work is to use a `Resume` statement immediately followed by another `On Error` statement. The `Resume` is within the error handler and diverts code to the `EndTry1` label. You must immediately set another `On Error` statement to avoid problems as the previous error handler will "resume". That is, it will be active and ready to handle another error. That could cause the error to repeat and enter an infinite loop.

To avoid using the previous error handler again you need to set `On Error` to a new error handler or simply use `On Error Goto 0` to cancel all error handling.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm teaching my students tomorrow.  After years of looking at this stuff... ie all of the documentation above http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm comes to mind as an excellent one...

I hope this summarizes it for others.  There is an `Err` object and an active (or inactive) `ErrorHandler`.  Both need to be handled and reset for new errors.

Paste this into a workbook and step through it with F8.

```
Sub ErrorHandlingDemonstration()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'this will error
    Debug.Print (1 / 0)

    'this will also error
    dummy = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("not gonna find me", Range("A1:B2"), 2, True)

    'silly error
    Dummy2 = "string" * 50

    Exit Sub

zeroDivisionErrorBlock:
    maybeWe = "did some cleanup on variables that shouldnt have been divided!"
    ' moves the code execution to the line AFTER the one that errored
    Resume Next

vlookupFailedErrorBlock:
    maybeThisTime = "we made sure the value we were looking for was in the range!"
    ' moves the code execution to the line AFTER the one that errored
    Resume Next

catchAllUnhandledErrors:
    MsgBox(thisErrorsDescription)
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    thisErrorsNumberBeforeReset = Err.Number
    thisErrorsDescription = Err.Description
    'this will reset the error object and error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    'this will tell vba where to go for new errors, ie the new ErrorHandler that was previous just reset!
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' 11 is the err.number for division by 0
    If thisErrorsNumberBeforeReset = 11 Then
        GoTo zeroDivisionErrorBlock
    ' 1004 is the err.number for vlookup failing
    ElseIf thisErrorsNumberBeforeReset = 1004 Then
        GoTo vlookupFailedErrorBlock
    Else
        GoTo catchAllUnhandledErrors
    End If

End Sub
```