# VBA: Microsoft Word process does not exit after combining many Word files into one

Tags: windows, vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to merge many Word files into one. I am doing this inside a VBA routine in MS Excel. The Word files are all in a folder named "files" and I want to create a new file "combinedfile.docx" in a folder one-level above that. The problem I'm facing is regarding how the Word process behaves after merging the files (whether or not it exits after the execution of the VBA function). On some machines, this process works fine (except that it has page 2 and the last page as blank), while on some others, the merged document contains a blank page and the Process Manager shows the Word process started by the VBA function as still running.

1. I am not used to VBA programming and as you can see in the code below, I don't know the right way to close an open document and exit a open Word process. If anyone could look at what I've done and suggest a way to solve this problem, it would be very helpful.
2. I am also interested to know if this is the right way to merge several Word files. If there's a better way, please let me know.

```
    'the flow:
    '  start a word process to create a blank file "combinedfile.docx"
    '  loop over all documents in "files" folder and do the following:
    '    open the file, insert it at the end of combinedfile.docx, then insert pagebreak
    '  close the file and exit the word process

    filesdir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + "files\"
    thisdir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
    singlefile = thisdir + "combinedfile.docx"

    'if it already exists, delete
    If FileExists(singlefile) Then
      SetAttr singlefile, vbNormal
      Kill singlefile
    End If

    Dim wordapp As Word.Application
    Dim singledoc As Word.Document
    Set wordapp = New Word.Application
    Set singledoc = wordapp.Documents.Add
    wordapp.Visible = True
    singledoc.SaveAs Filename:=singlefile
    singledoc.Close    'i do both this and the line below (is it necessary?)
    Set singledoc = Nothing
    wordapp.Quit
    Set wordapp = Nothing

    JoinFiles filesdir + "*.docx", singlefile

    Sub JoinFiles(alldocs As String, singledoc As String)
      Dim wordapp As Word.Application
      Dim doc As Word.Document
      Set wordapp = New Word.Application
      Set doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(Filename:=singledoc)
      Dim filesdir As String
      filesdir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + "files\"

      docpath = Dir(alldocs, vbNormal)

      While docpath  ""
        doc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.InsertFile (filesdir + docpath)
        doc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        docpath = Dir
      Wend
      doc.Save
      doc.Close
      Set doc = Nothing
      wordapp.Quit
      Set wordapp = Nothing  
    End Sub
```

Comment: You create two instances of Word, one in the main sub and another in the `JoinFiles()` sub. They look like they are being closed/quit correctly. What happens in the `JoinFiles` sub if you make `wordApp.Visible=True` and step thru it?

Comment: Where (after which statement) do you want me to add that statement?

Comment: Question Edited: I am also interested to know if this is the right way to merge several Word files. If there's a better way to do it, I'd be interested in it. Surely, something is wrong with this method: even when it works, the combined file has blank pages (after first doc, and at the end).

Comment: you should add some error handling and make sure youre still closing and unlinking  the word instance and/or document if any error occur. i sometimes face a similar issue with opening excel and word files with no error handler - they just hand in the processes tab in task manager.

Comment: @mehow, could you please let me know what kind of error handling you mean? an example would be great.

Comment: sure thing! [link1](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm), [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6da8809(v=vs.80).aspx), [link3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571), [link4](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-handling-errors-in-vba/339), [link5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-error-handling-in-vba-excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to optimize your code in following ways:

- open the WordApp only once and move files into it without closing/reopening
- no need to kill combineddoc upfront, it will be simply overwritten by the new file
- no need for a Word.Document object, all can be done in the Word.Application object

so the code gets a lot simpler:

```
Sub Merge()
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim FilesDir As String, ThisDir As String, SingleFile As String, DocPath As String
Dim FNArray() As String, Idx As Long, Jdx As Long ' NEW 11-Apr-2013

    FilesDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + "files\"
    ThisDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
    SingleFile = ThisDir + "combinedfile.docx"
    Set WordApp = New Word.Application

' NEW 11-Apr-2013 START
    ' read in into array
    Idx = 0
    ReDim FNArray(Idx)
    FNArray(Idx) = Dir(FilesDir & "*.docx")
    Do While FNArray(Idx) <> ""
        Idx = Idx + 1
        ReDim Preserve FNArray(Idx)
        FNArray(Idx) = Dir()
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve FNArray(Idx - 1) ' to get rid of last blank element
    BubbleSort FNArray
' NEW 11-Apr-2013 END

    With WordApp
        .Documents.Add
        .Visible = True

' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013 DocPath = Dir(FilesDir & "*.docx")
' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013 Do While DocPath <> ""
' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013     .Selection.InsertFile FilesDir & DocPath
' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013     .Selection.TypeBackspace
' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013     .Selection.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013     DocPath = Dir
' REMOVED 11-Apr-2013 Loop

' NEW 11-Apr-2013 START
        For Jdx = 0 To Idx - 1
            .Selection.InsertFile FilesDir & FNArray(Jdx)
            .Selection.TypeBackspace
            .Selection.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
        Next Jdx
' NEW 11-Apr-2013 END

        .Selection.TypeBackspace
        .Selection.TypeBackspace
        .Selection.Document.SaveAs SingleFile
        .Quit
    End With
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub

' NEW 11-Apr-2013 START
Sub BubbleSort(Arr)
Dim strTemp As String
Dim Idx As Long, Jdx As Long
Dim VMin As Long, VMax As Long

    VMin = LBound(Arr)
    VMax = UBound(Arr)

    For Idx = VMin To VMax - 1
        For Jdx = Idx + 1 To VMax
            If Arr(Idx) > Arr(Jdx) Then
                strTemp = Arr(Idx)
                Arr(Idx) = Arr(Jdx)
                Arr(Jdx) = strTemp
            End If
        Next Jdx
    Next Idx
End Sub
' NEW 11-Apr-2013 END
```

**EDIT 11-Apr-2013**
removed original comments in code
added array and bubblesort logic to guarantee files are retrieved in alphabetical order

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the code presented in the question is very basic- I don't know the caveats of VBA and just wanted to get something running. Your code looks much better. I will try this and write again.

Comment: This works great :)
However, a few strange things still happen. 

(1) Most importantly, the formatting of the combined file is different from the individual files', e.g., the combined file contains headers like page number and the line spacing also changes from 1 to 1.5. Similarly, a blank page is inserted after file 1.

(2) The files are combined in no order. With my previous code, the files were combined in the order of their filenames.

Any help to fix this would be great :)

Comment: ad 1) maybe your sources are based on different templates ... mine were all based on Normal.dotx ... ad 2) `Dir()` doesn't guarantee any sort order - if that's needed ... see EDIT

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it, and I faced the following problems: "ReDim Preserve FNArray(Idx - 1)" generates an Index Out of Range error. When I comment it out, the macro finishes without error, but the produced file (singlefile) is empty :(

Comment: do you have an `Option Base 1` declaration in your code? The above code asumes array indices starting with 0

Comment: and your info suggests you are already past the loop, so you should have N+1 elements in the array .... so maybe `Dir()` didn't find any files. Walk thru the sub in single step mode (F8) and look how the variables are being filled ...