# Conditionally checking if an XPath is correct in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
Postcode = driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='T_F2']/fieldset/div[1]/div/div[4]/span[2]").Text

CopytoClip (Postcode)

Range("b" & X).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

My code uses XPath to grab a postcode from a website before assigning it to  a variable. This variable is them passed onto my Copy to Clip sub which handles copying the value into my computers clipboard before pasting it into an Excel cell. The problem however is that my code will run the above a number of times for different web pages, some with no postcode in the specified XPath.

This leads to the code crashing, so I was hoping I could fix this with an if statement. My question is, can I conditionally search for whether or not the specified XPath exists on a webpage?

Something like...

```
If driver.findElementByXPath("...").DoesNotExist

Then

   Run rest of code...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element does not exist, an exception (or error) will be thrown.  In languages like Java and C#, the exception is a NoSuchElementException.

What you should do is use error handling to make your code run if the element doesn't exist.  Here are a couple of links to help point you in the right direction:

**[Example of this problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521270/webdriver-check-if-an-element-exists)**

**[Example of error handling in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-error-handling-in-vba-excel)**