# Why is 'On Error' always triggering as if the key is null?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to set up error handling in an Access app that connects to a SQL Server backend to prevent Access passing a null primary key to the server.

I'm using BeforeUpdate and code based on [Properly Handling Errors in VBA (Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-handling-errors-in-vba-excel)

My code is supposed to run the ErrHandler code if the user sets S_ID to null (or leaves it as null when creating a new record).  But instead it's always running the ErrHandler code.

```
Private Sub S_ID_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Dim trigger As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If Me.S_ID Is Null Then
    trigger = 1 / 0
End If

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox ("Key was null, fix it")
Resume Resume_spot

Resume_spot:

End Sub
```

I've yet to write the code for what I want Access to do when the error occurs, hence the useless `MsgBox` and lack of anything after `Resume_spot`.  Before I get that far I want to get the error handling to trigger properly.

Comment: Obviously not an answer, but shouldn't the ***backend*** be responsible for maintaining its own identity column integrity?  Why isn't it just defined as `NOT NULL` in SQL Server?

Comment: BTW, if your `MsgBox` includes `Err.Number` or `Err.Description`, it makes this pretty easy to debug.

Comment: *"(or leaves it as null when creating a new record)"* - this will **not** trigger the control's `BeforeUpdate` event.

Comment: @Comintern It is defined as `NOT NULL` but I don't want my users to have to parse SQL server ODBC failed messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers explain the solution, so I'll explain the *problem*.  Your error handler is catching a Run-time error 424: "Object required" on this line:

```
If Me.S_ID Is Null Then
```

The `Is` comparison operator requires that both sides of the test evaluate to objects.  `Null` is not an object, thus the error.  Your "trigger code" of `trigger = 1 / 0` that is intended to raise a division by zero error is never fired.

That said, if you need to test an error handler or create a specific error, it is much easier to just use `Err.Raise` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `IsNull`

Change:

```
If Me.S_ID Is Null Then
```

To:

```
If IsNull(Me.S_ID) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Why the strange construction with `trigger`?

Just do

```
If IsNull(Me.S_ID) Then
    MsgBox "Key was null, fix it"
    Cancel = True
End If
```

2- For a simple check like this, you don't need any code. Use a [Validation rule](http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html) for the form control.

3- All this doesn't cover the case where the user never starts entering anything in the control. This can be handled in `Form_BeforeUpdate()` by setting `Cancel = True` there.

Comment: I was using a validation rule, but Access flips its shit and doesn't allow you to exit the field until you enter something, so if the user opened a new record in error I'm going to get invalid data.