# EXCEL running efficiency

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to improve the efficiency of my following code which is a pretty easy copy paste task

```
For i = 2 To 60
some_data = xxx
some_data_2 = xxx


Sheets("template1").Select
Sheets("template1").Copy Before:=Sheets(20)


Sheets("example").Select
Range(Cells(some_data + 1, i), Cells(some_data + some_data_2, i)).Select
Selection.Copy



Sheets("template1 (2)").Select
Range("C5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I am only looping this for 60 sheets, then it took several minutes and Excel exited automatically(crahsed?). How can I improve its efficiency?

EIDT: Will it help if I try to rewrite the whole thing using python via for instance openpyxl?

Comment: Based on your provided code: see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: if `xxx` is static, they should be set outside the loop, not in it. Even better, if `some_data + some_data_2` is static, set that prior to the loop.  Probably won't make much difference timewise, but it's definitely more efficient.

Comment: if you are using `some_data + some_data_2` why not make the constant `some_data_2 = some_data + x`!? Then you can change this `some_data + some_data_2` to simply this `some_data_2`

Answer (score 0):

- You can Benefit from [How to Avoid Using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- You can also Make use of `Application.Screenupdating = False` at start of your code and `True` in the End. That should make it significantly faster.
- Include [Error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-handling-errors-in-vba-excel), Crashing could be because of Error that occurs somewhere in the Loop.

**Change your code without select & Activate like:**

```
    some_data = xxx
    some_data_2 = xxx


   For i = 2 To 60

    Sheets("template1").Copy Before:=Sheets(20)

    Sheets("example").Range(Cells(some_data + 1, i), Cells(some_data + some_data_2, i)).Copy

    Sheets("template1 (2)").Range("C5").Paste
```