# Excel VBA: For loop with Match function, OnError works if no match is found, but inserts empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop set up with a match function, so it checks if there is a match and then returns the result and repeats this for a defined number of times. I also have it set up so if there is an error, meaning if there is no match, it skips to the next loop. However, when no match is found, it leaves an empty row before inputting the next match below it. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

**The way my code currently works is like this:**

**ws1** has multiple columns and rows of data. The first cell on every row in column A is the title. The titles are from a fixed selection (it's a drop down) which are determined by a list that is on ws2

**ws2** has the list of titles, which is h3 until LastRow

**ws3** Upon button click, it will match any results that correlate with **variable_condition**, and if it can't find a match it will go to the next loop, then print it on multiple rows from row 4 onwards

On ws3 it also inserts a shape which is assigned a macro (and thus becomes a button) on each row

What actually happens is, if it can't find a match, an empty row appears with this shape in column I.

I'm trying to make it so there isn't a blank row with a button and instead it just inserts the next looped result

My code below:

```
Sub CardsCollection()

Set ws1 = Sheets("Database")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Insert")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print LastRow

Dim test_string As String
test_string = "H" & LastRow
Dim test_range As Range
Set test_range = ws2.Range(test_string)

variable_condition = Range("E2")

NxtRw = 4

On Error Resume Next
For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    row_num2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & myCell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!F:F=""" & variable_condition & """),0)")
    ws3.Range("A" & NxtRw).EntireRow.Value = ws1.Range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Value


Dim button_cell As String
    button_cell = "I" & NxtRw

    Dim bc_range As Range
    Set bc_range = Range(button_cell)

    Dim rect1 As Shape
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim clLeft As Double
    Dim clTop As Double
    Dim clWidth As Double
    Dim clHeight As Double

    Dim shpRec As Shape
    Set cl = Range(button_cell)

    With shpRec
        clLeft = cl.Left
        clTop = cl.Top
        clWidth = cl.Width - 5
        clHeight = cl.Height - 5
    End With


    Set shpRec = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, clLeft, clTop, clWidth, clHeight)


        With shpRec
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 177, 135)
        .Line.Visible = False 'True
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "INSERT"
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 24
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "SF Pro Display Black"
    End With

    NxtRw = NxtRw + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

EDIT: Updated code

```
Sub CardsCollection()

Call last_used_sort


Set ws1 = Sheets("Database")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Insert")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print LastRow

Dim test_string As String
test_string = "H" & LastRow
Dim test_range As Range
Set test_range = ws2.Range(test_string)

Dim row_num2 As Long

variable_condition = Range("E2")


NxtRw = 4


For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    row_num2 = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    row_num2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & myCell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!F:F=""" & variable_condition & """),0)")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If row_num2 <> -1 Then
    ws3.Range("A" & NxtRw).EntireRow.Value = ws1.Range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Value

    Dim button_cell As String
    button_cell = "I" & NxtRw


    Dim bc_range As Range
    Set bc_range = Range(button_cell)


    Dim rect1 As Shape
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim clLeft As Double
    Dim clTop As Double
    Dim clWidth As Double
    Dim clHeight As Double

    Dim shpRec As Shape
    Set cl = Range(button_cell)

    Dim button_cell As String
    button_cell = "I" & NxtRw


    Dim bc_range As Range
    Set bc_range = Range(button_cell)


    Dim rect1 As Shape
    Dim rngToCheck As Range
    Dim clLeft As Double
    Dim clTop As Double
    Dim clWidth As Double
    Dim clHeight As Double

    Dim shpRec As Shape
    Set cl = Range(button_cell)

    Set shpRec = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, clLeft, clTop, clWidth, clHeight)


        With shpRec
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(242, 177, 135)
        .Line.Visible = False 'True
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "INSERT"
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 24
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Name = "SF Pro Display Black"
    End With


    NxtRw = NxtRw + 1

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: So basically if `rownum2` is nothing then the code should just skip to the next iteration without performing anything further ?

Comment: Skip to the next iteration and not produce an empty row as a result of finding nothing - yep

Comment: On error resume next will just skip the line with the error, not the entire loop. You would want something like: `On Error GoTo NextLoop` and place `NextLoop:` on the row before `Next`

Comment: Try Changing `NxtRw = NxtRw + 1` with `If IsNumeric(row_num2) Then NxtRw = NxtRw + 1`.

Comment: @Mikku, that will still insert the shape, but then you will get two shapes on top of each other, making more of a mess.

Comment: Yeah @Luuklag .. Your approach will be best in this case.

Comment: @Luuklag yep works great, thanks! Thanks Mikku as well!

Comment: @Sam I see you just edited your code, please leave the question be as the question was, since now it is no longer a question. I just finished writing up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution is to isolate the source of potential error and handle it.  I see several options here

Using your `Evaluate` code

```
For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    row_num2 = -1
    On Error Resume Next
        row_num2 = Evaluate( ... )
    On Error GoTo 0
    If row_num2 <> -1 Then

        '...
        ' rest of your loop code

    End If
Next
```

Using a more conventional `WorksheetFunction` approach, which will also throw a runtime error if a match is not found

```
For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    row_num2 = -1
    On Error Resume Next
        row_num2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.MATCH( ... )
    On Error GoTo 0
    If row_num2 <> -1 Then

        '...
        ' rest of your loop code

    End If
Next
```

Using `Application.Match` which will *not* throw a runtime error, but retrn a error value instead

```
Dim row_num2 As Variant
For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    row_num2 = Application.MATCH( ... )

    If Not IsError(row_num2) Then

        '...
        ' rest of your loop code

    End If
Next
```

Note: I don't fully understand your Match formula, so haven't tried to translate to the Match function version.

Comment: I'll test this out with my spreadsheet in a couple of minutes and report back how it went. Thanks for your help! Do you have any insights into my comment earlier? I'll paste it here: Do you know of a way to use Match to find a different result than the one already produced? For example, you see how my code inserts a button? If I amended the code to insert a different button called 'refresh', is it possible to make it so if the user clicks this button it will replace that row with a different match? Different to the one already written to the row

Comment: @sam broadly, sure that possible.  (But I don't see where you assign an action to the button you insert now?)  You can use `Application.Caller` to shape that called a macro, and use the shape position to betermine the row to update

Comment: Nice write up Chris. @Sam could also be usefull to read this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-handling-errors-in-vba-excel

Comment: Ah I didn't realise I hadn't updated the code with the Call subroutine(). I don't have a problem getting the buttons to be assigned with a macro, but the bit I can't get my head around is telling the match to look for a different match other than the one that's already been written into the row

EDIT: for example, I thought about an if statement, if row x is the same as match value then match again. But match will just return the same value each time, right? Is there a way to tell match to go to the next result

Comment: @sam  still using Match, I think the only option would be to change the serch range to start after the last found cell.

Comment: So I would get the match to return the row number like it is now, then the refresh match would change from A:A for example to A row number to A1000 for example? EDIT: or, for neatness, rather than A1000 I could just do LastRow

Comment: I'll give that a go when I try your code and ill let you know how it goes - thanks for your help

Comment: @Sam please keep in mind that you can at any time change the answer you "accept". So if you found this answer more usefull then mine, click on the green tick at my answer to remove it and assign it any were else if you see fit.

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for letting me know, once I've implemented the other code I'll correct it if needs be - thanks

Comment: So I've tried to implement the first option, using Evaluate, and I'm getting a Type Mismatch error indicating that it didn't find a match and has stopped proceeding to the next loop - any ideas?

Comment: @Sam  Something I didn't notice before: you havn't DIM'd row_num2 in your posted code.  Have you in your actual code?

Comment: @Sam  In testing just now, if row_num2 is a variant, there is no runtime error (returns an error value).  If row_num2 is a (say) Long then there is an error and On Error Resume Next masks it.  So, you can't have implemengted the code as I posted it.  Maybe update your Q with latest code

Comment: I've updated the original post with my code. I included the dim row_num2 As Variant at the top. Maybe it's my placement of the End If?

Comment: @sam perhaps I wasn't clear: you need to remove `On Error Goto NextLoop` and `NextLoop:`.  Alos,since you are DIM'g row_num2 as Variant, a structure along the lines of my option 3 would be more appropriate (still using Evaluate).  If you still get an error it won't be on the Evaluate line.  Report back on which line it is on

Comment: I've updated my original post's edit (the 2nd block of code) with your advice and it works now! Thanks! I'm going to try and attempt the refresh subroutine now

Comment: @chrisneilsen I'm having trouble writing my match using variables as the range instead of directly writing it like I did before (eg. A:A)

`row_num3 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'found_match=""" & condition1 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'found_match2=""" & condition2 & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'condition3=""" & flow_cell & """),0)")` I've got found_match set up to be `found_match = "A" & row_num2 & ":A" & lastrow3` for example

Answer (score 1):

First off, using `On Error Resume Next` is one of the worst lines of code one could write in VBA, since it only hides errors. It doesn't show you what is wrong with your code, or perhaps your assumption in your code are wrong. So you really should avoid using this at all. If your code relies on a line like this to function it should really be improved.

Now for a quick fix on your code, you want it to be the case that if no match is found, you resort to the next iteration. As your comparison statement is rather hard to read without sample data I'll do you the quick fix below:

So change your `On Error Resume Next` part in the code like this:

```
NxtRw = 4

On Error GoTo NextLoop
For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    row_num2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & myCell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!F:F=""" & variable_condition & """),0)")
    ws3.Range("A" & NxtRw).EntireRow.Value = ws1.Range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Value
```

And indicate where the code should continue like this:

```
    NxtRw = NxtRw + 1
NextLoop: 'this indicates where to continue
Next

End Sub
```

It would be better to check if a match could be possible with an `If` statement, so you could simply rely on that logic to skip to the end of the loop.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! While I'm here, do you know of a way to use Match to find a different result than the one already produced? For example, you see how my code inserts a button? If I amended the code to insert a different button called 'refresh', is it possible to make it so if the user clicks this button it will replace that row with a different match? Different to the one already written to the row

Comment: This is actually terrible advise.  It's just as bad as an unconstrained On Error Resume Next.  What if a different error occurs half way through the rest of the loop code?  It will jump to the next iteration of the loop, leaving whatever was half done, still half done.  The correct why is to use a `On Error Resume Next` tightly bound with a `On Error Goto 0` around the code that might error, followed by a test to see if the code worked, then conditionally execute the rest of the loop code.

Comment: @chrisneilsen are you able to write an example in context like the others? I think I understand your concept but unsure exactly the positioning of where it should go

Comment: @chrisneilsen ofcourse this isnt the best solution, but a quick fix. As I did indicate in my answer.

Comment: @Sam As an example, the `WorksheetFunction.Match` function returns an error if the value cannot be found.  Hence `var = 0: On Error Resume Next: var = WorksheetFunction.Match("Value", Sheet1.Range("A1:A7"),0): On Error GoTo 0` will set `var` to the row that `"Value"` is found on, unless it isn't in the range `A1:A7`, in which case `var` will be 0.  `If var>0 Then` can later be used to prevent errors.