# How can I call a subroutine after an error?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm working on user-proofing a VBA app in Excel and I realized I'm constantly rewriting a lot of the same code to create specific error messages that are fed strings of info for the user to be able to tell me when they inevitably call me to say they're getting errors.

I want to create something like this to simply call on each error and pass the particulars:

```
Sub GenericError(ErrNum As Long, ErrDesc As String, sequence As String, errtype As String)
'In case of error, returns actual error code and calls for abort; if no abort then can debug
Dim msgstrng As String
msgstring = sequence & " error " & errtype _
    & vbLrCf & "Error code " & ErrNum & " - " & ErrDesc
MsgBox msgstring, , sequence & " Error!"
cont = Abort_Check()
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Then ideally I could use something like

```
On Error Call GenericError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "Startup Sequence", "File Not Found")
'code that opens a file....
On Error goto 0
```

It seems like On Error only works with goto or resume; there are a bunch of modules that would need this in a lot of subs so writing basically this in a bunch of different GoTo blocks is annoying. Is there a solution for me to use an error to call a sub like this?

Comment: Try `workbook_sheetbeforedelete`?

Comment: There's been a lot written about  generic error handlers. Eg [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028288/445425)

Comment: I was giving an example possibility; there will be hundreds of users on this and lots of things that could go wrong

Comment: I guess we approach life differently. Good day.

Comment: To mitigate errors, consider the UI features available, e.g. protect ranges on a sheet, protect workbook structure to prevent sheet deletion, keep `xlVeryHidden` any sheets your code needs to read so users can't change them etc. Also, consider log files to capture the error details; the user won't necessarily remember everything on the MsgBox - if you output a log file to a shared drive, then you could consult that after a user alerted you, and have proper debug info to you

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulate your error generators in a try function

```
Public Function TryDoThisThing( byval ipInput1 as variant, byval input2 as variant,byref opReturnValue as variant, byref opErrorNumber as long, byref opErrorDescription as String) as boolean

   On Error Resume Next
   opReturnValue = DoThistThing(ipInput1, ipInput2)
   TryDoThisThing = err.number = 0
   opErrorNumber = err.number
   opErrorDewscription = Err.description
   Err.Clear

Exit Function
```

Then in your code you'd have

```
If not TryDoThisThing(val1, val2, myResult, myErrNo,myErrDesc) then

    GenericError myErrNo, myErrDesc, sequence , errtype
    <any other corrective actions>
end if
```

Comment: @scottcraner  Thanks for the edit.  Unfortunatly I hit a wrong key combination and the answer was added before I'd finished typing, that's why it looked so bad.